# Using eclipse to create a new project

Tags: java, eclipse, project, new-project

I tried to create a new project "hbv8" by going to file -->new java project, and I used the default settings.

Why is my hbv8 has an red x at the corner of its icon? It also automatically imported the source code from hbv7 with me importing it. Can someone please help? Many thanks in advance!

[image]

The problems window shown as below, but I didn't import those things from hbv 7 so I can't figure out what was the problem..
[image]

Comment: Try to clean your project. `Project->Clean`

Comment: If you were using the default settings it shouldn't have imported hbv7 into hbv8.

Comment: Go to the problems view or window. Its generally on the bottom of right side pane in eclipse. You can see the list of errors there. Tell us what the errors are.

Comment: I tried clean but it didnt work..

Comment: Thanks! I edited with a capture of the errors. The src.hucklebuckle was from hbv7, but I didn't import them when I created hbv8..

Answer (score 0):

Your source files are in folder `hbv8/src/src/hucklebuckle` - note the two `/src` folders.

Eclipse expects the files to be in `hbv8/src/hucklebuckle` (just one `/src`)

So move the files or recreate the project.